# Accessing pixel of a sprite

Tags: java, libgdx

My question is simple, yet I cannot find answer to it.
1. Can you access pixel values of a sprite in libgdx? Let's say I have sprite `sprite`, how to get it's [0,0] RGBA value.
2. If I want to create normal map, is it faster to load it from RGBA to Java array, or access it from sprite.

I'm really sorry if it is in documentation, I tried to find it but couldn't. If you did find it there, any suggestions how to effectively search for things in java-docs?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found an answer. It appears the solution to that is to use `Pixmap` instead of sprite.